# Capture Media Errors - React Native Google Cast

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, chromecast, google-cast-sdk, react-native-google-cast

I've successfully integrated [React Native Google Cast](https://react-native-google-cast.github.io/docs/getting-started/installation.html) into my React Native project, and I'm able to cast some videos without any issues. However, there are some videos that I'm unable to cast, and I'm not seeing any error messages in the log. I've checked the stream URL and confirmed that CORS is enabled for it.

Here's the stream URL: https://seivod.secure.footprint.net/F1451/playlist.m3u8

I'm wondering if there's a way to capture error logs. If it's possible to create logs using the receiver app, can you guide me on how to create the receiver using the React Native Google Cast library? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions you may have.